# Update reactive variable from event

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm using

```
Template.uploadFile.events({
  'change .set-file': function ( event, template ) {
    var file = event.currentTarget.files[0];

    [...]
  }
});
```

when uploading a file.

I want to read every row in the file and insert each row as a document in a collection.

The problem is that I want to reactively show the user how many rows has been created.

First I need to set the number of lines in the file as a variable. I have to set the variable inside my event since I only know the number of lines after the file has been read (i.e. the event has been fired).

I guess I have to do something like

```
Template.uploadFile.helpers( {
  numRows: function () {
    return ?;
  },
  numInsertedRows: function () {
    return ?;
  },
} );
```

Number of inserted rows could just be the number of documents in my collection; however, I guess it's quite memory demanding to read from the collection at the same time as I'm inserting into the collection.

So I think it's better to just use plain variables, since all the information should be available without asking the database.

I have a loop

```
rowsInFile.forEach( function ( row ) {
    // add 1 to number of inserted rows
} );
```

but that loop should also change the one of the reactive variables.

I guess I should use a reactive variable. Am I right? Is it the most memory efficient way to do it?

Comment: I would not insert the rows from the client side, but rather get the file itself on the server and process it there. The main reason for it is that in case the user gets disconnected or closes the browser window during the operation, it will be cut and it will may difficult to cleanly apply it again.

Comment: How can I do that? It sounds more appealing than doing it on the client.

Comment: How large is the expected data file? Is it feasible to send the data as an array of strings to the server? If it is not expected to be too large, the easiest option (by far) is to do it via a method. You should probably provide some more information regarding the type of processing that you are doing.

Comment: It is actually a very large file. I want to insert each row in the file (maybe 10.000 rows) into a collection, so I guess it is way better to do this operation directly on the server instead of via the client. I can eventually use papa parse to parse the csv file and get an array of the rows to be inserted.

Comment: Well, this is too broad for a SO question, but if it is something that is used often (so it cannot be done once or twice manually by you via a direct console or something), I'd start with something like the following mix: `CollectionFS` or another upload mechanism for sending the files to the server, [mikowals:batch-insert](https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert) for the server side bulk insertion and `raix:eventemitter` for progress reports.

Answer (score 0):

You might be over-complicating matters. Just `count()` the documents in the collection:

```
Template.uploadFile.helpers({
  numRows: function(){
    return myCollection.find({}).count();
  }
});
```

You could do the same for the number inserted assuming you can write a query that finds them reliably. Otherwise you can just increment a *Session* or *reactive* variable in your loop and return that.